# Use Findstr to find string and save it to a file without outputing error

Tags: cmd

I'm trying to find some string "tn=6192548188_hao" in all the files in my C:/, and this is the Code I used in Console:

```
findstr /S/I ".*tn=6192548188_hao.*" * >"D:/21.txt" 2>nul
```

But when I checked 21.txt in D:/, there's nothing inside, but when I used

```
findstr /S/I ".*tn=6192548188_hao.*" *
```

There's actually something in the console other than error, so is there anything wrong with my command? Since I'm new to findstr, this may be a really trivial problem. But anyway, thanks for your attention!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've tried you code, and it worked perfectly for me.

You should be aware that `/` is a switch on windows and `\` a directory separator. The translation usually occurs if the target is a filename.

The `.*` in the regex seems redundant.

Comment: I used .* since the string always begin with something as a prefix. I've also run as administrator, but it doesn't give me anything new. So is there any method to print all the result on console without echoing errors? Since when I used the later code, it always ends with "out of memory". Thanks for your attention!

Comment: Ok, I've used (findstr /S/I ".*tn=6192548188_hao.*" * 2>nul) and seems to get the answer on the console, but it's strange that there's nothing in 21.txt as well. There may be some problem with my computer? Or is the "out of memory" the primary problem now? Anyway, thanks for your help!

Comment: Odd - as I said, your code worked for me (W7). On the *regex* front, I found `.*` was indeed redundant, since `*` matches 0 or more occurrences. In theory, `..*string..*` should match `1 or more any-characters` at either end. Weel, with my experiment it matched at the end, but with "..*string", `cmd` ran off to La-la land, using CPU but doing no I/O (according to *process explorer*.) I'll include @dbenham in the hope of a comment...